# jQuery "Can only call NodeList.item on instances of nodelist"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am writing a website using jQuery and I am trying to post a form to another PHP file without leaving the page. So then I found a way to post a form using jQuery. However when I post the data to the PHPpage I get this error:

> Can only call NodeList.item on instances of nodelist

I have no idea on what to do. The code I am using is this:

```
function upload(text){
  $.post("update.php",{
    text:text,
    comment: null,
    parent: null,
    like: null
   }, function(){alert('Thanks');});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="post_text"></textarea>
<button onclick="upload(document.getElementById('post_text'))">Upload</button>
```

`

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You're not showing the right code. The problem is with the line of code that uses the `.item()` method. Your code here doesn't show that.

Comment: If you are using jquery, don't use the old `onclick` attribute. Go with a event handler on the form (which I don't even see the form tags).

Comment: I understand, however that is the only jquery/javascript code on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're providing a DOM Element to the `text` property, which jQuery is then attempting to encode resulting in the error you see. To solve this, provide the `value` of the element instead.

Also note that using the `on*` event attributes should be avoided where possible in favour of unobtrusive event handlers. As you've already included jQuery in the page you can use that. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#upload').click(function() {
    $.post("update.php", {
      text: $('#post_text').val(),
      comment: null,
      parent: null,
      like: null
    }, function() {
      alert('Thanks');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="post_text"></textarea>
<button id="upload">Upload</button>
```